Can Paul’s statements on women’s ministry be harmonised with God appointing Deborah and Huldah as prophets
We are aware of Paul’s statements regarding women’s ministry and that Paul’s writing is by inspiration of the Holy Spirit .. but how do we harmonize what Paul says on the matter, with God’s appointment of OT women prophets. Reference should also be made to Priscilla teaching Apollos (possibly with Paul’s support and encouragement ) and Phillip the evangelist having four daughters that prophecied .

1 Timothy 2:11, 12 - A woman must learn in quietness and full
submissiveness. I do not permit a woman to teach or to exercise
authority over a man; she is to remain quiet.
Judges 4:4 - Now Deborah, a prophetess, the wife of Lappidoth, was
judging Israel at that time.


Deborah judged Israel in conjunction with Barak. Priscilla instructed Apollos in conjunction with Aquila. Women prophesy but with heads covered, demonstrating that the man is the head of the woman. There is no 'harmonising' necessary. Nothing is out of balance in these matters.

Huldah instructing King Josiah

.. thanks for your answer but you haven’t mentioned Huldah

Also Paul is saying a woman mustn’t teach a man .. the fact another man is there doesn’t change what Paul is saying .. so we haven’t reached harmonisation yet .

@NigelJ - do you have a Bible reference for your assertion about a joint judgeship?  Barak wanted a joint leadership of the military campaign (Judges 4:8) but did not share her judging responsibilities.  How else could be Barak be "summoned" by Deborah (V6)?

I am just researching 1. who the writers of scripture were and 2. researching who the apostles were and 3. researching who the ministers were who ministered to the churches in the days of the apostles . . . . . .and I shall report back when I have finished my research.

These two passages are in very different contexts, over 1000 years apart. Applying Paul's instructions to the church to ancient Israel is very anachronistic.

1 Timothy 2:11-12

A woman must learn in quietness and full submissiveness. I do not permit a woman to teach or to exercise authority over a man; she is to remain quiet.

It seems Paul's primary concern is that women exercising authority over men contradicts his teaching. We may associate this stance with his teaching in 1 Corinthians 11:3;

But I want you to realize that the head of every man is Christ, and the head of the woman is man, and the head of Christ is God.

Paul argues that allowing women to exercise authority over men would disrupt the divine order, suggesting that if women could have authority over men, then men could have authority over Jesus and in turn, over God.
In the Old Testament, anyone-even a donkey (Numbers 22:28)- could convey the Lord's message, with no restrictions on women. So why did Paul oppose women teaching the Gospel? Frankly, the exact reason isn't entirely clear.
It's possible that because all twelve apostles were male and were the first to receive Jesus' revelation of God's kingdom, Paul believed that women might not have had enough knowledge or trustworthiness to preach the gospel accurately in the 1st century. If this is accurate, then with the abundant resources available today for studying, women should be allowed to teach, provided they do so without assuming an overly authoritative manner.

Thank you for this answer .

Let me deal with this question in two stages - about the NT attitude to Women generally and then with the specifics of 1 Tim 2:11, 12.  For completeness I will also offer some comments in 1 Cor 14:34, 35.
NT Attitude to Women
Ancient Jewish and Israelite culture was both agrarian and patriarchal.  Roman customs were less agrarian but extremely patriarchal to the point of misogynistic.  Let us observe the following:

The ancient Israelite patriarchal society did not prevent women from inheriting property.  Num 27:1-11, 36:1-12, Josh 17:3-6.
Women could be significant leaders, eg., Deborah.  Judges 4.
Women could be prophets of God; eg, Miriam (Micah 6:4, Ex 15:20, 21), Deborah (Judges 4:4), Huldah (2 Kings 22:14-20), Isaiah’s wife (Isa 8:3), Anna (Luke 2:36), The four daughters of Phillip (Acts 21:8, 9), etc.
Women could buy and sell property.  Prov 31:16.
Women could earn independent income and use it at their discretion.  Prov 31:11, 16, 18, 20, Acts 16:12-15, 40.
Men were required to treat women and wives with great respect – see “Marriage”.  In fact, they were to treat wives as Jesus would love them – enough to give His life for them.  Eph 5:25.
A man could not divorce his wife on whim and marry another without being guilty of adultery.  Matt 19:9 (very different from Roman law), Gen 2:24.
A man could not deprive his wife of marital privileges.  1 Cor 7:2-4.  (The same was equally required of women.)
Paul had female co-workers in Euodia and Syntyche (Phil 4:2, 3) as well as Junia the apostle (Rom 16:7).  Nympha appears to be the leader of the church that met in her house at Laodicea (Col 4:15).  John also addressed an epistle to a female church leader (2 John 1).
In addition to the above, women could hold other offices such as deaconess or “minister” (Rom 16:1).
The New Testament church was specifically instructed to care for elderly women who could not support themselves .  1 Tim 5:9-13.
Women were allowed to teach men.  The female leader, Priscilla taught the Apostle Apollos “more adequately”, Acts 18:26.  It is significant that Priscilla is listed before her husband, Aquila, in this passage.  King Lemuel was taught by his mother, Prov 31:1-9.
Women were permitted to pray and prophesy in public meetings, 1 Cor 11:5.
Gal 3:28 declares that all gender distinctions are out of place for the Christian congregation

There are numerous examples in the Bible of women being treated very badly, just as there are throughout history, even into modern times.  This does not make such appalling behavior acceptable, according to the above ideals.  This leaves us with the final “problems” of Paul’s comments in 1 Tim 2:11, 12 and 1 Cor 14:34, 35.
1 Timothy 2:11, 12
The Greek text of 1 Timothy 2:11, 12, according to Nestle-Aland (UBS 5th Ed) is the basis for most translations in English.  According to the Majority Text (eg, Farstad et al), the Byzantine Text (Robinson and Pierpont), Family 35 text (Wilbur Pickering), the Patriarchal text, and the Textus Receptus, the order of the first three words of v12 is reversed, but this changes neither the translation nor the meaning of the text.
As commonly translated in modern versions, the NIV is typical, but its margin offers a significant alternative.

“(v11) A woman [wife]margin should learn in quietness and full
submission.  (v12) I do not permit a woman [wife]margin to teach or to
assume authority over a man [husband]margin; she must be quiet.”  1
Timothy 2:11, 12 NIV.

It is no wonder that this single passage is both the magna carta of ecclesiastical sexism and a thorn in the side of gender equality.
Therefore, how are we to understand this verse?  Understanding this verse is complicated by the fact that the central verb, “authenteo”, translated “assume authority over” occurs only here in all the New Testament.  It is immediately obvious that such a translation is inconsistent with both the theology of Scripture and its practice.  See the above list to observe the remarkably liberated status that women enjoyed under Bible ideals.
Therefore, to properly understand this verse, we must better understand the vocabulary and idiom, because it is clear that such a simplistic translation, as above, is out of place in Paul’s writing and the rest of the Bible.
This verb, “authenteo” is used only here in verse 12 in all the New Testament.  It is an unusual choice if Paul simply intended the idea of “authority” for which a variety of more common words are available.  Indeed, the Analytical Lexicon of the Greek NT (Friberg et al) entry is, “strictly, of one who acts on his own authority; hence have control over, domineer, lord it over”.  The BDAG entry is even stronger: “assume a stance of independent authority, give orders to, dictate to, … practically = ‘tell a man what to do’”.
Jerome’s Latin Vulgate (400 AD) translates this word as “dominari” = domineer.
A very impressive study by Albert Wolters [Albert Wolters, Journal for Biblical Manhood and Womanhood, JBMW vol 11-1, p44, 2006] clearly shows that this verb (and its cognate relatives) means to “have mastery over”.  (See also its use as a noun in Wisdom 12:6, “murderer”, and 3 Macc 2:29, “master”.)  Cynthia Long Westfall agrees,

“In the Greek corpus, the verb authenteō [which includes the
infinitive authentein] refers to a range of actions …  However, the
people who are targets of these actions are harmed, forced against
their will (compelled), or at least their self-interest is being
overridden, because the actions involve an imposition of the subject’s
will, ranging from dishonor to lethal force.” [Cynthia Long Westfall, Paul and Gender: Reclaiming the Apostle’s Vision for Men and Women in Christ (Grand Rapids, MI: Baker Academic, 2016), 292.]

Such behavior is out of place in both the home and the Christian congregation for anyone including women.  Indeed, Jesus and the apostle Peter specifically forbade Christian leaders (or anyone else) “lording it over” other members of the congregation (Matt 20:25, 26, Mark 10:42, 43, 1 Peter 5:3).  Thus, a domineering attitude is inappropriate behavior for both men and women, but presumably, Timothy had problems in his congregation(s) with some difficult and bossy women that Paul advised him to address.
Further, Paul’s advice in Eph 5:21—28 gives authority to husbands over wives, but only consistent with the loving, self-sacrificing attitude of Christ to the Church.  Again, complete mastery of anyone over another is out of place in the Christian community and home (Eph 5:21) by both men and women.
It is very instructive that that the immediate context of this instruction is vs 9 and 10 where Paul instructs women to dress with modesty and decently (ie, not provocatively or to call attention to themselves).  It appears that he then expands upon this point about how women are to teach – without being domineering; and to learn in calmness.
Hendiadys
In verse 12 there is a Greek construction, often used by Paul, called “hendiadys”. In 1 Tim 2:12, the construction, “neither teach nor domineer”, idiomatically means, “do not teach in a domineering way”; “do not ram your ideas down men’s throats in an overpowering way”, or similar.
Silence or Quietness?
The final sentence of this tricky verse 12 contains Paul’s injunction, “she must remain quiet” (NIV), or, “she is to keep quiet” (NRSV), or, “but to remain quiet” (NASB), or, “but to be in silence” (KJV & NKJV), or, “she is to remain quiet” (ESV), etc, with similar results for v11.
We first observe that the phrase in v12 begins with the conjunction, “but” which necessarily introduces a related but opposite idea.  Again, it is clear that Biblical women were NOT required to be silent and this is clear by a simple comparison of the translation of the same word, hesuchia, earlier in the same passage, verse 2, which applies to all Christians to be “peaceful/tranquil and calm”.  As used here, this obviously does not imply that Christians are to remain silent or quiet!
Therefore, for consistency we should use a similar idea in verse 12, thus rendering the latter part of verse 12, “but to be calm”, without implying quietness or silence.
Singular vs Plural
Up to verse 10, Paul uses the plural, “women”, presumably applying to all Christian women.  However, in verses 11, and 12, he switches to the singular, “woman” or “wife”.  I am inclined to think that Paul specifically has wives in mind here, hence his change of grammatical number.  However, whether this is true or not does not alter the point – silence is NOT advocated so much as calmness.
Again, the same word, hesuchia, is used to describe the way a wife should learn and teach; and, again, it does not imply quietness; indeed, both the Socratic and Rabbinic teaching methods involved much discussion and dialogue between the student and teacher.
Therefore, Paul simply states what modern pedagogy has confirmed: that a student cannot learn while arrogant or surly.  Thus Paul says (v11), “Let a wife learn in calmness and subjection.”  As such, this is a perfect introduction to what comes after in V12 about eliminating domineering attitudes in the family.
Of course, such advice is applicable to husbands (as shown above) as well as wives but the more urgent problem in Timothy’s parish was possibly with overly bossy wives, as further evidenced by the “reason” quoted immediately after about Adam and Eve to encourage over-confidant women to be a little more humble and less arrogant.
Translation of 1 Tim 2:11, 12
Let us now translate 1 Tim 2:11, 12 using the above principles:

“Let a wife learn in calmness and subjection.  I do not permit a wife
to foist her ideas on the husband, but to be calm.”

With this understanding, we have much better agreement with the rest of Scripture and a more sensitive handling of the Greek idiom.  Further, it is consistent with other Scriptural instruction to be humble and imitate Christ such as Matt 11:29, Phil 2:5, 1 Cor 2:16.
1 Cor 14:34, 35
Again, the NIV provides a good, representative translation of this verse.
“Women should remain silent in the churches. They are not allowed to speak, but must be in submission, as the law says.   If they want to inquire about something, they should ask their own husbands at home; for it is disgraceful for a woman to speak in the church.”  1 Cor 14:34, 35.
We should immediately observe three points about this text that are obvious:

The women (or wives) being in subjection should be read in the context of ALL Christians being subject to one another (Eph 5:21)
Paul’s instruction here does not mean that women (or wives) should remain silent in church or that they are forbidden to speak or preach.  1 Cor 11:5 makes this clear by providing instruction on how women were to speak and preach.
The advice Paul gives is in the context of calming the rabble that had developed in Corinth as various “prophets” competed to speak in tongues and prophesy.  Thus it is not a plea for silence as much as order as confirmed in 1 Cor 14:40, “let all things be done decently and in order”.

There may have also been a local cultural component to this advice as well.

Thank you to all who have worked so hard answering this question . I’m new to this site ( I asked the question ) and it required me to add a tag ..so I put ‘contradiction’ .. I don’t personally think there are any contradictions in the Bible because the Bible is the word of God .. perhaps I would have preferred to say ‘apparent contradiction ‘ .. but thank you for answering I’m going to carefully read the answers now .. thank you .

Thank you again for your thorough answer .. I don’t understand the term up-voting put I pressed the arrow upwards to show approval .. Christian love to all ..and thanks again ..

Also .. I seem to have scored -4 today .. how did that happen ?

@markdanks - there are a few on this site, contrary to the site rules, who downvote anything they disagree with.  This is bad practice - I reserve my downvotes for anything factually and manifestly incorrect.  Downvotes get -2 points and upvotes get +10 votes.

@markdanks, Adding to Dottard's comment, a positive personal story. I recently read two answers on a question about the Trinity. One was from a JW writer, who posted his answer but also upvoted the orthodox Christian answer. He said that he wanted to acknowledge a thoughtful and well researched answer, even though he didn't agree with it. I thought that was a very impressive attitude, one that we can all do well to model.

@PeterKirkpatrick - great example

@Peter Kirkpatrick .. yes a nice , thoughtful attitude .. thanks to all who have have taken the trouble to give me answers .. some of them would have taken a  long  time to put together ..
